# Subtracting unit of minutes from Rails datetime value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

In one view of my Rails project, I want to show the user how long it is until the next game. To do so, I have a datetime value in my game table for `game_start`.

I need to do this in the view, and to me, the easiest solution would be to just subtract the `game_start` from `Time.now` (i.e. if the game starts at 4:05 PM and it's 4:00 PM, it would return 5 minutes). I try:

```
 <p><%= Quiz.where(category: session[:category]).first.game_start - Time.now %> </p>
```

Ok, so it checks the Quiz table, finds a the `game_start` of the game matching the param and subtracts `Time.now`.

However, while my `timeformats.rb` currently shows units of time in Hours and Minutes via `"%I:%M %p"`, this particular subtraction produces a value in seconds only.

Is it possible to force the subtraction to honor my TimeFormats, or, even better, tell it to return a value in minutes only?

Comment: Divide by 60 perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Time is more complex than you think

Outputting the number of minutes might seem like a pretty simple task but there are several factors you are not weighing in:

- what happens when `game_start` is in the past?
- what happens when `game_start` is several days into the future/past?

Rails provides some pretty nifty date helpers such as `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` which helps with outputting time diffs in a human friendly way:

```
[1] pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object
[2] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(50.minutes.from_now)
=> "about 1 hour"
[3] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(5.minutes.from_now)
=> "5 minutes"
```

### Time and caching

Dealing with user timezones or `distance_of_time_in_words` can be very problematic from a caching standpoint since it needs to be recalculated on every request.

A better alternative could be to output the time as a timestamp and let the client figure out the diff.

```
<%= content_tag :time, quiz.game_start, 
  class: 'time-diff', 
  datetime: quiz.game_start.utc.iso8601
%>
```

This is an example using `jQuery` and [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to format the time. You can do it with vanilla JS but its so lengthy that its a question on its own.

```js
// recursive function that runs once on startup and then every minute
(function updateTimeDiff( interval ){
  interval = interval || 60000; // default polling to 1 minute
       
  $(".time_diff").each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var m = moment($el.attr('datetime') );
    
    $el.text(  m.fromNow() );
    // this is a unformated diff in minutes
    console.log( m.diff(moment(), 'minutes', true) );
  });    

   setTimeout(updateTimeDiff, interval);
})();
```

```html
<!-- this is just to power the snippet. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<time class="time_diff" datetime="2016-02-17T15:26:12-04:00">2016-02-17T15:26:12-04:00</time>
```

Comment: On a side note - don't use the session for categories or whatever. Use query param as it does not violate the stateless nature of REST.

Comment: I am making this as the answer. I ended up going with the first route, altering the code to `<p>Countdown to Start: <%= ((quiz.game_start - Time.now).to_i)/60 %></p>`. In my use case, I only care about how many minutes there are from Time.now until the start of the game, so this was an easy way to do it. I am looking through the second scenario though.